# Proxychains can't load process....: No such file or directory

Tags: macos, homebrew

I have tried running Proxychains on both an Intel Mac and an M1 Mac. I am completely new to this sort of thing and just want to learn. I am not a coder.

When I run `proxychains firefox google.com` on Intel Mac it returns `-bash: proxychains: command not found`. When I run the same command on M1 it returns `zsh: command not found: proxychains`.

Most instructions I've read show `proxychains` as the command to use, but, as shown above, that isn't working. I've read one suggestion to use `proxychains4` as a command (though I'm not sure why) so I tried that. When I run `proxychains4 firefox google.com` both computers return the following:

```
% proxychains4 firefox google.com
[proxychains] config file found: /opt/homebrew/etc/proxychains.conf
[proxychains] preloading /opt/homebrew/Cellar/proxychains-ng/4.14/lib/libproxychains4.dylib
proxychains can't load process....: No such file or directory
```

`locate proxychains` shows the path `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/proxychains-ng/4.14/lib/libproxychains4.dylib` is visible on both computers.

I have searched high and low for an answer on why this won't work but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2):

Find the path of Firefox on your computer and then enter it after proxychains4, like below.

```
$ locate firefox

$ proxychains4 /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox ipinfo.io
```

I have spent a few days trying to get Firefox working with proxychains4. I found it and now sharing it.

References:

- [proxychains can't load process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59817244/proxychains-cant-load-process)
- [How to Find Your Firefox Profile Folder on Windows, Mac, and Linux](https://www.howtogeek.com/255587/how-to-find-your-firefox-profile-folder-on-windows-mac-and-linux/)